# Error in Gathering Statistics on the network traffic

Tags: python, ctypes, libpcap

I'm creating a function to calculate packet capture delay using Python and pcap, but this error happens. I'm taking this function from a C example as I'm new to Python. This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prototype_sniffer_v1.py", line 266, in processing_pkts
    Bps = ((pkt + 8) * 8 * 1000000) / (delay) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'LP_c_ubyte' and 'int'
  Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function: <function processing_pkts at 0x7fbed299df70>
```

This link [Gathering Statistics on the network traffic](https://npcap.com/guide/npcap-tutorial.html#npcap-tutorial-statistics) contain the C code example.

This is C example:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <pcap.h>

#include <tchar.h>
BOOL LoadNpcapDlls()
{
  _TCHAR npcap_dir[512];
  UINT len;
  len = GetSystemDirectory(npcap_dir, 480);
  if (!len) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in GetSystemDirectory: %x", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
  }
  _tcscat_s(npcap_dir, 512, _T("\\Npcap"));
  if (SetDllDirectory(npcap_dir) == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in SetDllDirectory: %x", GetLastError());
    return FALSE;
  }
  return TRUE;
}

void usage();

void dispatcher_handler(u_char *, const struct pcap_pkthdr *, const u_char *);


void main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  pcap_t *fp;
  char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
  struct timeval st_ts;
  u_int netmask;
  struct bpf_program fcode;
  
  /* Load Npcap and its functions. */
  if (!LoadNpcapDlls())
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't load Npcap\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Check the validity of the command line */
  if (argc != 2)
  {
    usage();
    return;
  }
    
  /* Open the output adapter */
  if ( (fp= pcap_open(argv[1], 100, PCAP_OPENFLAG_PROMISCUOUS,
                      1000, NULL, errbuf) ) == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"\nUnable to open adapter %s.\n", errbuf);
    return;
  }

  /* Don't care about netmask, it won't be used for this filter */
  netmask=0xffffff; 

  //compile the filter
  if (pcap_compile(fp, &fcode, "tcp", 1, netmask) <0 )
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"\nUnable to compile the packet filter. Check the syntax.\n");
    /* Free the device list */
    return;
  }
    
  //set the filter
  if (pcap_setfilter(fp, &fcode)<0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"\nError setting the filter.\n");
    pcap_close(fp);
    /* Free the device list */
    return;
  }

  /* Put the interface in statstics mode */
  if (pcap_setmode(fp, MODE_STAT)<0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"\nError setting the mode.\n");
    pcap_close(fp);
    /* Free the device list */
    return;
  }


  printf("TCP traffic summary:\n");

  /* Start the main loop */
  pcap_loop(fp, 0, dispatcher_handler, (PUCHAR)&st_ts);

  pcap_close(fp);
  return;
}

void dispatcher_handler(u_char *state,
  const struct pcap_pkthdr *header,
  const u_char *pkt_data)
{
  struct timeval *old_ts = (struct timeval *)state;
  u_int delay;
  LARGE_INTEGER Bps,Pps;
  struct tm ltime;
  char timestr[16];
  time_t local_tv_sec;

  /* Calculate the delay in microseconds from the last sample. This value
   * is obtained from the timestamp that the associated with the sample. */
  delay = (header->ts.tv_sec - old_ts->tv_sec) * 1000000
    - old_ts->tv_usec + header->ts.tv_usec;
  /* Get the number of Bits per second */
  Bps.QuadPart=(((*(LONGLONG*)(pkt_data + 8)) * 8 * 1000000) / (delay));
  /*                                            ^      ^
                                                  |      |
                                                  |      | 
                                                  |      |
                         converts bytes in bits --       |
                                                         |
                    delay is expressed in microseconds --
  */

  /* Get the number of Packets per second */
  Pps.QuadPart=(((*(LONGLONG*)(pkt_data)) * 1000000) / (delay));

  /* Convert the timestamp to readable format */
  local_tv_sec = header->ts.tv_sec;
  localtime_s(&ltime, &local_tv_sec);
  strftime( timestr, sizeof timestr, "%H:%M:%S", &ltime);

  /* Print timestamp*/
  printf("%s ", timestr);

  /* Print the samples */
  printf("BPS=%I64u ", Bps.QuadPart);
  printf("PPS=%I64u\n", Pps.QuadPart);

  //store current timestamp
  old_ts->tv_sec=header->ts.tv_sec;
  old_ts->tv_usec=header->ts.tv_usec;
}


void usage()
{
  printf("\nShows the TCP traffic load, in bits per second and packets per second."
         "\nCopyright (C) 2002 Loris Degioanni.\n");
  printf("\nUsage:\n");
  printf("\t tcptop adapter\n");
  printf("\t You can use \"WinDump -D\" if you don't know the name of your adapters.\n");

  exit(0);
}
```

This is my Python function:

```py
import libpcap as pcap
import ctypes as ct
import socket
import getopt
import os
import time

import funcoes_auxiliares

from struct import *
from libpcap._platform import sockaddr, sockaddr_in, sockaddr_in6
from pcaptestutils import *

pd = ct.POINTER(pcap.pcap_t)()

if not is_windows:
    breaksigint = False

    #static void sigint_handler(int signum _U_)
    def sigint_handler(signum):
        global pd
        global breaksigint
        if breaksigint:
            pcap.breakloop(pd)


def main(argv=sys.argv[1:]):
    global program_name
    program_name = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])

    global pd
    global breaksigint
    global ip_afinet
    global ip_afinet6
    
    # Exceção para os parâmetros
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "i:mnt:" if is_windows else "bi:mnrst:")
    except getopt.GetoptError:
        usage()

    device = None
    timeout = 1000
    nonblock = 0 
    immediate = False
    
    if not is_windows:
        sigrestart  = False
        catchsigint = False

    for opt, optarg in opts:
        if not is_windows and opt == '-b':
            breaksigint = True
        elif opt == '-i':
            device = optarg.encode("utf-8")
        elif opt == '-m':
            immediate = True
        elif opt == '-n':
            nonblock = 1
        elif not is_windows and opt == '-r':
            sigrestart = True
        elif not is_windows and opt == '-s':
            catchsigint = True
        elif opt == '-t':
            try:
                timeout = int(optarg)
            except:
                error('Timeout value "{}" is not a number', optarg)
            if timeout < 0:
                error("Timeout value {:d} is negative", timeout)
            if timeout > INT_MAX:
                error("Timeout value {:d} is too large (> {:d})",
                      timeout, INT_MAX)
        else:
            usage()
            
    expression = args
    
    errbuf = ct.create_string_buffer(pcap.PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE)

    # ----------------------------------------------------------
    # Lista de dispositivos disponíveis
    if device is None:
        deviceList = ct.POINTER(pcap.pcap_if_t)()
    if pcap.findalldevs(ct.byref(deviceList), errbuf) == -1:
        error("{}", ebuf2str(errbuf))
    if not deviceList:
        error("Não há interfaces disponíveis para captura")
        
    print('\nAvailable network devices:')
    devices = deviceList
    while devices:
        device = devices.contents
        print("\t[*] {}".format(device.name.decode("utf-8")))
        devices = device.next
        
    device = deviceList[0].name
    ip_tuple = funcoes_auxiliares.getStdIp(deviceList[0])
    (ip_afinet, ip_afinet6) = ip_tuple
    
    # print(ip_afinet)
    # print(ip_afinet6)
    
    pcap.freealldevs(deviceList)
    # ----------------------------------------------------------

    errbuf[0] = b"\0"
    
    # if not is_windows:
    #     # If we were told to catch SIGINT, do so.
    #     if catchsigint:
    #         action = sigaction()
    #         action.sa_handler = sigint_handler
    #         sigemptyset(ct.byref(action.sa_mask))
    #         # Should SIGINT interrupt, or restart, system calls?
    #         action.sa_flags = SA_RESTART if sigrestart else 0
    #         if sigaction(SIGINT, ct.byref(action), NULL) == -1:
    #             error("Can't catch SIGINT: {}", strerror(errno))
    

    pd = pcap.create(device, errbuf)
    
    if not pd:
        error("{}", ebuf2str(errbuf))
        
    # define o comprimento do instantâneo a ser usado 
    # em um identificador de captura quando o 
    # identificador é ativado para snaplen.
    status = pcap.set_snaplen(pd, 65535)
    if status != 0:
        error("{}: pcap.set_snaplen failed: {}",
              device2str(device), status2str(status));
        
    if immediate:
        try:
            status = pcap.set_immediate_mode(pd, 1)
        except AttributeError:
            error("pcap.set_immediate_mode is not available on this platform")
        if status != 0:
            error("{}: pcap.set_immediate_mode failed: {}",
                  device2str(device), status2str(status))
            
    status = pcap.set_timeout(pd, timeout)
    if status != 0:
        error("{}: pcap.set_timeout failed: {}",
              device2str(device), status2str(status))
        
    status = pcap.activate(pd)
    if status < 0:
        # pcap.activate() failed.
        error("{}: {}\n({})",
              device2str(device), status2str(status), geterr2str(pd))
    elif status > 0:
        # pcap.activate() succeeded, but it's warning us
        # of a problem it had.
        warning("{}: {}\n({})",
                device2str(device), status2str(status), geterr2str(pd))
        
    localnet = pcap.bpf_u_int32()
    netmask  = pcap.bpf_u_int32()
    if pcap.lookupnet(device, ct.byref(localnet), ct.byref(netmask), errbuf) < 0:
        localnet = pcap.bpf_u_int32(0)
        netmask  = pcap.bpf_u_int32(0)
        warning("{}", ebuf2str(errbuf))
    
    fcode = pcap.bpf_program()
    
    cmdbuf = " ".join(expression).encode("utf-8")
    if pcap.compile(pd, ct.byref(fcode), cmdbuf, 1, netmask) < 0:
        error("{}", geterr2str(pd))

    if pcap.setfilter(pd, ct.byref(fcode)) < 0:
        error("{}", geterr2str(pd))
    if pcap.setnonblock(pd, nonblock, errbuf) == -1:
        error("pcap.setnonblock failed: {}", ebuf2str(errbuf))
    
    # -----------------------------------------
    # create a save file for write 
    savefile = 'testsavefile'
    savefile = savefile.encode('utf-8')
    pdd = pcap.dump_open_append(pd, savefile)
    if not pdd:
        error("{}", geterr2str(pd))
    # -----------------------------------------

   
    print("\nSniffing on device: \n\t*{}*".format(device2str(device)))

    if os.path.exists("qtdPktpTime.txt"):
        os.remove("qtdPktpTime.txt")
            
    cont_i = 0
    while cont_i <= 10:
    # while True:
        
        packet_count = ct.c_int(0)
        status = pcap.dispatch(pd, -1, processing_pkts,
                 ct.cast(ct.pointer(packet_count), ct.POINTER(ct.c_ubyte)))
        
        # execute for write in save file
        pcap.dispatch(pd, -1, pcap.dump,
                               ct.cast(pdd, ct.POINTER(ct.c_ubyte)))
        if status < 0:
                break
        if status != 0:
            print("\n{:d} packets seen, {:d} packets counted after "
                  "pcap.dispatch returns".format(status, packet_count.value))
            ps = pcap.stat()
            pcap.stats(pd, ct.byref(ps))
            print("{:d} ps_recv, {:d} ps_drop, {:d} ps_ifdrop".format(
                  ps.ps_recv, ps.ps_drop, ps.ps_ifdrop))
            print("\n")
        cont_i += 1
    
    
    if status == pcap.PCAP_ERROR_BREAK:
        # We got interrupted, so perhaps we didn't manage to finish a
        # line we were printing. Print an extra newline, just in case.
        print()
        print("Broken out of loop from SIGINT handler")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if status == pcap.PCAP_ERROR:
        # Error.  Report it.
        print("{}: pcap.dispatch: {}".format(program_name, geterr2str(pd)),
              file=sys.stderr)

    pcap.freecode(ct.byref(fcode))
    pcap.close(pd)

    funcoes_auxiliares.plotGraf1()

    return 1 if status == -1 else 0

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# AUXILIAR FUNCTIONS
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Convert a string of 6 characters of ethernet address into a dash separated hex string
def eth_addr (a) :
    b = "%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x" % (ord(a[0]) , ord(a[1]) , ord(a[2]), ord(a[3]), ord(a[4]) , ord(a[5]))
    return b

# Função callback usada no processamento dos pacotes
@pcap.pcap_handler
def processing_pkts(arg, hdr, pkt):
    counterp = ct.cast(arg, ct.POINTER(ct.c_int))
    counterp[0] += 1
    
    old_ts_tv_sec = 0
    old_ts_tv_usec = 0
    
    pkt_addr        = hdr.contents
    pkt_time_cap    = pkt_addr.ts
    pkt_len         = pkt_addr.len
    pkt_caplen      = pkt_addr.caplen
    
    eth_length = 14
    
    eth_header = pkt[:eth_length]
    eth = unpack('!6s6sH' , bytes(eth_header)) 
    eth_protocol = socket.ntohs(eth[2])
    
    count_pkt = 0
    
    delay = (pkt_time_cap.tv_sec - old_ts_tv_sec) * 1000000 - old_ts_tv_usec + pkt_time_cap.tv_usec
    
    Bps = (ct.cast(pkt,ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint64))[1] * 8 * 1000000) / (delay)
    Pps = (ct.cast(pkt,ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint64))[0] * 1000000) / delay
    
    old_ts_tv_sec = pkt_time_cap.tv_sec
    old_ts_tv_usec = pkt_time_cap.tv_usec
    
    print('Bps: ' + str(int(Bps)))
    print('Pps: ' + str(int(Pps)))
    
    time_cap = time.ctime(pkt_time_cap.tv_sec)
    
    # Parser IP packets
    if eth_protocol == 8:
        ip_header = pkt[eth_length:20+eth_length]
        
        iph = unpack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , bytes(ip_header))
    
        version_ihl = iph[0]
        version = version_ihl >> 4
        ihl = version_ihl & 0xF

        iph_length = ihl * 4

        ttl = iph[5]
        protocol = iph[6]
        s_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[8]);
        d_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[9]);
        
        # print('Version: ' + str(version) + '| IP Header Length: ' + str(ihl) + ' | ' + 'TTL: ' + str(ttl) + ' | ' + 'Protocol: ' + str(protocol) + ' | ' +'Source Address: ' + str(s_addr) + ' | ' +'Destination Address: ' + str(d_addr) + ' | ' + 'length: ' + str(pkt_len) + ' | ' + 'cap length: ' + str(pkt_caplen) + ' | ' + 'Cap time: ' + str(pkt_time_cap))
        print('\nVersion: ' + str(version) + '| IP Header Length: ' + str(ihl) + ' | ' + 'TTL: ' + str(ttl) + ' | ' + 'Protocol: ' + str(protocol) + ' | ' +'Source Address: ' + str(s_addr) + ' | ' +'Destination Address: ' + str(d_addr) + ' | ' + 'length: ' + str(pkt_len))
        
        count_pkt = 0
        if s_addr == ip_afinet:
            # print('confirma ip')
            count_pkt += 1
            arq_qtdPktpTime = open("qtdPktpTime.txt", "a")
            arq_qtdPktpTime.write(time_cap + ',' + str(counterp[0]) + '\n')
            
            # funcoes_auxiliares.plotGraf1()
        
        # TCP protocol
        if protocol == 6:
            
            t = iph_length + eth_length
            tcp_header = pkt[t:t+20]
            tcph = unpack('!HHLLBBHHH' , bytes(tcp_header))          
            source_port = tcph[0]
            dest_port = tcph[1]
            sequence = tcph[2]
            acknowledgement = tcph[3]
            doff_reserved = tcph[4]
            tcph_length = doff_reserved >> 4
            
            print('Source Port: ' + str(source_port) + ' >> Dest Port: ' + str(dest_port) + ' >> Sequence Number: ' + str(sequence) + ' >> Acknowledgement: ' + str(acknowledgement) + ' >> TCP header length: ' + str(tcph_length))
            
            h_size = eth_length + iph_length + tcph_length * 4
            # data_size = len(pkt) - h_size
            # data_size = pkt_len - h_size
            
            #get data from the packet
            data = pkt[h_size:pkt_len]
            # print('Data : ' + str(data))
        
        # UDP procotol
        elif protocol == 17:
            u = iph_length + eth_length
            udph_length = 8
            udp_header = pkt[u:u+8]
            
            udph = unpack('!HHHH' , bytes(udp_header))
            source_port = udph[0]
            dest_port = udph[1]
            length = udph[2]
            checksum = udph[3]
            
            # print('Source Port: ' + str(source_port) + ' >> Dest Port: ' + str(dest_port) + '>> Length: ' + str(length) + ' >> Checksum: ' + str(checksum))
            print('Source Port: ' + str(source_port) + ' >> Dest Port: ' + str(dest_port) + ' >> Checksum: ' + str(checksum))
            h_size = eth_length + iph_length + udph_length
            
            # data = pkt[h_size:pkt_len]
            # print(data)
    # pcap.dump      

# função para captura e uso de parametros no execução do código no terminal
def usage():
    print("Usage: {} [ {} ] [ -i interface ] [ -t timeout] "
          "[ expression ]".format(program_name,
          "-mn" if is_windows else "-bmnrs"), file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   

if __name__.rpartition(".")[-1] == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Can help me to solve this ?? I appreciate any tips

Comment: A lot of definitions missing. Make a [mcve]. What do you think `pkt` represents?  You mentioned a C example are you porting it to Python? show it

Comment: From the error message, `pkt` must be a ctypes-wrapped C `BYTE*`.  To compute Bps (bytes per second), you probably want `pkt_len` not that actual pointer.

Comment: My bad, sorry The function is it: **delay = (pkt_time_cap.tv_sec - old_ts_tv_sec) * 1000000 - old_ts_tv_usec + pkt_time_cap.tv_usec** but in python, the C function is: **delay=(header->ts.tv_sec - old_ts->tv_sec) * 1000000 - old_ts->tv_usec + header->ts.tv_usec**, in this link: [Gathering Statistics on the network traffic](https://npcap.com/guide/npcap-tutorial.html#npcap-tutorial-statistics).

Comment: **pkt** is a packet captured by the function pcap.dispacher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C code the OP is porting and generating an error in Python is:

```c
  /* Calculate the delay in microseconds from the last sample. This value
   * is obtained from the timestamp that the associated with the sample. */
  delay = (header->ts.tv_sec - old_ts->tv_sec) * 1000000
    - old_ts->tv_usec + header->ts.tv_usec;
  /* Get the number of Bits per second */
  Bps.QuadPart=(((*(LONGLONG*)(pkt_data + 8)) * 8 * 1000000) / (delay));
  /*                                            ^      ^
                                                  |      |
                                                  |      | 
                                                  |      |
                         converts bytes in bits --       |
                                                         |
                    delay is expressed in microseconds --
  */
  /* Get the number of Packets per second */
  Pps.QuadPart=(((*(LONGLONG*)(pkt_data)) * 1000000) / (delay));
```

The Python code is missing the casting and dereferencing of the `pkt_data + 8` byte pointer calculation.  Since `*(LONGLONG*)(pkt_data + 8) == ((LONGLONG*)(pkt_data))[1]`, the Python code implements cast and dereference of the latter version:

```py
   delay = (pkt_time_cap.tv_sec - old_ts_tv_sec) * 1000000 - old_ts_tv_usec + pkt_time_cap.tv_usec
   Bps = ct.cast(pkt,ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint64))[1] * 8 * 1000000 / delay
   Pps = ct.cast(pkt,ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint64))[0] * 1000000 / delay
```

Since there isn't a functional example I'll demonstrate by creating a byte pointer to two 64-bit values to test the code is correct.  The original code was adding 8 to a byte pointer, casting to a 64-bit pointer and dereferencing it.  That's the same thing as casting directly to a 64-bit pointer and indexing the 2nd value, e.g. `*(LONGLONG*)(pkt_data + 8) == ((LONGLONG*)(pkt_data))[1]`:

```py
>>> import ctypes as ct
>>> data = (ct.c_uint64 * 2)(100,200)
>>> pkt = ct.cast(ct.byref(data), ct.POINTER(ct.c_ubyte))
>>> pkt
<__main__.LP_c_ubyte object at 0x000002D38C9BA5C0>
>>> pkt + 8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'LP_c_ubyte' and 'int'
```

Above demonstrates the same error as the OP due to `pkt` being a byte pointer.  Below casts the pointer back to a 64-bit pointer and accesses the 2nd value:

```py
>>> ct.cast(pkt,ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint64))[1]
200
```

Comment: I tried as you instructed, but I got very large numbers. I know I'm working with seconds, but are these numbers right?

Bps: 74589436749.52322
Pps: 9323679593.690403

Comment: @D-LA since I can't run your code, I don't know if there is anything else wrong.  Unless your network is 74Gb/s and your have 9 billion tiny packets per second, it is probably wrong.  I can only fix the error you posted.  Logic errors require a [mcve] and enough information to verify the code is correct.

Comment: @D-LA Actually, I just noticed a bug in my port of the C code.  The + 8 should be added to the byte pointer before the cast.  Let me fix that and update the answer.

Comment: You're right. I should have posted my code here by now, sorry. In the next post I will post my code.

Comment: @D-LA fixed my casting now.  See if your numbers make more sense.

Comment: @D-LA Also FYI, the recently edited question code isn't the code that produced the error message posted as it has the erroneous version of my initial answer instead, so the question doesn't make sense now to others.  Probably should rollback that edit.

Comment: you mean like this: 

`Bps = ((8 + ct.cast(pkt,ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint64))[1]) * 8 * 1000000) / (delay)`

Comment: @D-LA No, the +8 is accounted for by dereferencing the 2nd 64-bit value with [1].  See my `Bps =` line of code above.

Comment: I also tried it in the form of the `Bps =` line, but the number is still large, so I tried it the way above.

Comment: @D-LA Adding an additional `8 +` is wrong, that just makes the value 64_000_000 bigger.  And the `Pps =` line should use `Pps = (ct.cast(pkg,ct.POINTER(ct_c_uint64))[0) * 1000000) / delay;` because it doesn't do `+ 8` so is accessing the first 64-bit value.  How large are the new values?

Comment: I tried this form: and edited the example. In the C example the output is given by `printf("BPS=%I64u ", Bps.QuadPart);`. what does that mean ?

Comment: @D-LA It means Bps was a `LARGE_INTEGER` Windows union type, and it is printing the 64-bit value of the variable.  In Python it would just be `print(Bps)`.

Comment: I tried this form:

`Bps = (ct.cast(pkt,ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint64))[1] * 8 * 1000000) / (delay)
    Pps = (ct.cast(pkt,ct.POINTER(ct.c_uint64))[0] * 1000000) / delay`

And one for the exits is:

`Bps: 93999021
Pps: 9323763161`

And i print this form:
`print('Bps: ' + str(int(Bps)))
    print('Pps: ' + str(int(Pps)))`

Even following your recommendations I can't see what I'm doing wrong, sorry :(
`

Comment: @D-LA 94MBps is reasonable.  What numbers do you get from working C code?

Comment: So there's the point that was confusing me. I believed that this large number was a wrong output, but it is Bits per second, which converting to MBps, there is a reasonable output. But what about Pps? Isn't a number a lot something yet?

Comment: I still couldn't compile the C code, as I use linux. And I found no replacement for the `tchar.h` library